# My Motherboard Compatibility List does not List a GDDR6 Graphics Card. Can I install it?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility

I have [MSI A320M PRO-VD/S V2](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/A320M-PRO-VDS-V2/Overview) motherboard and on its [compatibility](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/A320M-PRO-VDS-V2#support-vga) page, there is a list of supported GPUs. In the "Memory Type" column, the highest/latest (I guess) type is GDDR5X. Can I install [nVIDIA GTX 1660 Super](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/geforce/graphics-cards/gtx-1660-super/) [graphics card](https://www.amazon.in/Gigabyte-GeForce-Graphics-Windforce-Gv-N166SOC-6GD/dp/B07YYZGM51/ref=sr_1_22?dchild=1&qid=1608126874&refinements=p_36%3A1000000-2500000&rnid=1318502031&s=computers&sr=1-22) that has GDDR6 memory type?

Comment: Motherboard Qualified Vendor Lists (QVL) are never 100% complete. GPU compatibility has nothing to do with the onboard memory on the card itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard doesn't even know what kind of RAM is on the GFX card.
It only talks to the GFX card via the PCIe bus and doesn't see the RAM directly.

As your motherboard has a 16 lane PCIe 3.0 slot any PCIe 3.0 GFX card should work in that slot. (Just make sure that the card, if it has an extra plug for power, has that plug connected to the PSU. This specific card doesn't need it, but other cards do need more power than can be supplied via the PCIe slot.)

Anyway: Any compatibility list in the PC world just means "this is tested and verified by us". It never means "anything else is incompatible".
There is no way a motherboard manufacturer can test every GFX card on the market. The compatibly guide is just that: A guide.

Comment: Actually any PCIe 1.0 or newer, x1 or wider card _should_ work. PCIe has great backward and forward compatibility and scales with the number of lanes. There are exceptions to this rule, for example RTX 2080 doesn't work with PCIe 1.x boards, but pairing hardware that old with an RTX card would be silly anyway.